# Support for ankle inversion trauma during swimming

Tags: recovery, swimming

Assume you have an ankle inversion trauma and you cannot move your ankle for 2-6 months without having it in tight bind when doing sport. You otherwise support your foot at a moment by Aircast's ankle support. 
However, you cannot swim with it.

**How can you support your ankle to stay rigid when swimming?** 
I am not sure if elastic bind is ok because it absorbs all the dust from water to itself. 
It may also not support enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, you probably can't. The ankle and foot are one of the prime movers of the kick, and they require some motion. You can get an elastic to bind your ankles together so you are only doing pull exercises, but even that won't guarantee no movement. You also can't push off walls that way.

Comment: It's borderline off topic, but I think if you clarify "tight bind", and what type of injury you originally had (Ankle inversion, eversion, etc.) then you could get some suggestions along the lines of what you are looking for.

Comment: http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/shoulder-brace-for-judo : That's an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an inversion or eversion type injury (Fancy terms for rolling your ankle, the most common kind of sprain), the main taping is going to be to try and prevent the same injury again. Most of the time the taping job is going to be a U shaped type stirrup configuration, pulling the tension opposite the direction of the injury and then taping around the leg in series to hold the tape tight. This is going to be more important with weight bearing, lateral direction change sports such as tennis or soccer, and becoming progressively less critical with non/slight weight bearing, linear activities such as swimming and cycling.

With swimming, it is very unlikely (unless you get really clumsy on a flip turn) that you are going to invert or evert your ankle on the wall during a push off, and the main motion is going to be plantar or dorsiflexion. (The same motion of stepping on or releasing the gas pedal in a car). It's also almost completely non weight bearing, which is an advantage.

If the action of pointing or raising your toes causes no pain, then it is *probably* safe for you to swim without taping your ankle. I would caution you, however, to consult with your doctor or physical therapist, as there may be other complications. As a precaution, you can tape your ankle (It takes a bit of practice to do it well on yourself) and swim, as there are water resistant tapes that you can purchase. But again, check with your PT/doc, they may say that swimming is safe to do without any support (Although just in case, I would wear the air cast on the slippery pool deck).